# How prevalent is adoption of IEC and/or IPC standards among the major electronics manufacturers, especially CPU makers like Intel & AMD?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, cpu, ram

I spent part of the weekend learning about the history of the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) and IPC (originally an abbreviation for Institute of Printed Circuits) and their standards.

IPC was founded in 01957 (about the same time that vacuum tube computers were being replaced by transistor-based computers) by [the following six companies](https://www.ipc.org/ipc-history):

1. Electralab (which later merged with Printed Electronics Corporation
   to become Epec),
2. Printed Electronics Corporation,
3. Photocircuits Corporation (which closed in 02007),
4. Methode (still in operation as Methode),
5. Tingstol (I'm unable to find any history on this company),
6. Graphik Circuits Division of United Carr (I'm unable to find any history on this company).

It's very interesting to me that IBM was founded in 01911 but was not a part of IPC at founding. As I read [more about IPC](https://www.ipc.org/ipc-history), I'm also interested in seeing that IBM apparently became involved by 01963, but having not yet finished reading the history of IPC, it's not yet clear to me how much a role IBM has played in IPC standards.

Similarly, Intel was founded in 01968 by Moore and Noyce, but based on searching (I still haven't finished reading the entire history) I see no mention of Intel or Moore or Noyce in this IPC history until 1988, and then no mention of Intel after that year. And I also see no mention of AMD in this IPC history.

The standard IPC-A-610 (Acceptability of Printed Circuit Assemblies) was first published in 01983, and is still in use, with the latest revision of this standard being H, published in 2020 September.

I'm a relative newbie to this subject, but I suspect that despite the fact that it was founded around the time of transistor-based computers, the IPC standards don't relate very strongly (or perhaps at all) to the manufacture of CPUs, RAM, and related components that companies like Intel and AMD make. Searching the term "CPU" in IPC-A-610H finds no hits.

I found nothing that seemed relevant to CPUs at IPC, and searching https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Electrotechnical_Commission_standards for CPU turns up no hits, so it seems to me that neither IEC nor IPC have ever published standards for CPUs.

This leaves me wondering if huge companies like IBM, Intel, AMD, and On Semiconductor have always used their own, internally-developed electrical and mechanical standards documents for their products rather than any IPC (or IEC or ANSI or ISO et. al.) standards?

I'm aware of *architectures* like RISC and CISC for CPUs but I've always had the impression that these relate more to the instruction types and the processing of instructions (would it be correct to think of this as software, or perhaps firmware?) and less to the physical and electronic design and layout of a CPU.

I've searched the web for answers to this question/curiosity, but haven't found anything definitive.

So can anyone here please enlighten me? It occurs to me that I might know so little about the subject that my question makes no sense: maybe these are now two entirely separate industries (printed circuit boards like mainboards and daughter cards according to standards like IPC-A-610 versus microscale or nanoscale integrated circuits like CPUs with some entirely separate standards body?).

I get the impression that in the industry of integrated circuits like CPUs and RAM, IPC and IEC standards just don't apply. If that's true, then what standards documents do exist for CPUs and RAM? Are they entirely proprietary? And maybe that's why I can't expect an AMD CPU to work in a mainboard that was designed for an Intel CPU; at least, that used to be true... not sure if it's still true.

Comment: What's up with the weird 5-digit dates that look like octal?

Comment: Thanks for asking! "* The [Long Now Foundation uses five-digit dates](https://longnow.org/about/), the extra zero is to solve the deca-millennium bug which will come into effect in about 8,000 years." I'm a member of this really cool non-profit, and I support their mission ("We hope to foster responsibility in the framework of the next 10,000 years.") so I write my years with five digits to help raise awareness. See https://longnow.org/clock/ for more about them. :)

Comment: @KevinFordTheSubmariner For someone asking about standards you have blithely ignored the ISO standard for writing dates. In the process you have confused more than one reader. Not at all "really cool".

Comment: "[The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum)" —Andrew Stuart "Andy" Tanenbaum (born 01944), the first Dean of the Advanced School for Computing and Imaging (ASCI) in the Netherlands.

Comment: Project looks cool but the 5-digit date thing won't solve any bugs (I hope you realize that). As for your question, I'm not entirely sure I understand it but: designing and producing PCBs has essentially nothing to do with designing and producing ICs. And yes most(?) CPU designs are proprietary. (You could look at OpenSPARC  for a large "open source processor" - does not include the silicon design AFAIK.)

Answer (score 3):

The IPC standars are mainly for printed circuit boards to get manufacturing practices aligned with designers and with each other. It also sets forth requirements for dangerous voltages on a PCB and other things.

The IEC standards are safety standards that generally prevent people from building devices that could cause harm or injury to people. If a product is plugged into AC mains, it has the potential to kill someone or start a fire. Many entities (like OSHA, or maybe your local fire warden amongst many others) require that products are tested to these standards. Another thing the IEC standards do is make sure a load connected to AC mains isn't sending harmful harmonic frequencies to other loads on AC mains (or turning AC mains into a radiator).

Many products are tested to IEC 61010 which considers anything over 63V a dangerous voltage and has different requirements for handling it.

Take a look at a power supply for a PC (like [this one](https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/RMx_2018_Manual.pdf)), it has been tested to IEC 60950-1-2005.

> IEC 60950 is the safety standard applicable to mains-powered or
> battery-powered information technology equipment, including electrical
> business equipment and associated equipment, with a rated voltage not
> exceeding 600 V. The standard is also applicable to such information
> technology equipment:
>
> - Designed for use as telecommunication terminal equipment and telecommunication network infrastructure equipment, regardless of the
>   source of power
> - Designed and intended to be connected directly to, or used as infrastructure equipment in, a cable distribution system, regardless
>   of the source of power
> - Designed to use the AC mains supply as a communication transmission medium
>
> The application of SANS / IEC 60950 is intended to reduce the risk of
> injury or damage due to the following:
>
> - Electric shock
> - Energy related hazards
> - Fire
> - Heat related hazards
> - Mechanical Hazards
> - Radiation
> - Chemical hazards

Source: https://isert.co.za/safety-testing-sans-iec-60950-1.html

At the end of the day, for a PC the power supply (and maybe fans, but I could not find any requirements for fans) will be the thing that needs to conform to safety standards as everything else is low voltage. This is different than FCC testing, which tests unintentional radiators (like CPU's, motherboards and video cards) to make sure they aren't interfering with radios.

The standards that do apply to internal PC components are BUS standards like PCIE and DDR. CPU's (and other components) also have absolute maximum specifications (for power, temperature and timing) that must be followed to avoid damage to the part.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know IPC is mostly interested on the assembly/testing part of the electronic lifecycle. They say, for example, the best way to  make fabricable boards, various kind of materials/coating, assembly procedures and so on. Solderability? IPC. Masking and coating? IPC. File formats for fabrication? IPC

The other huge entity is JEDEC which actually registers component packages, signal levels and so one (it also has some standards on quality/manufacturing). TTL/CMOS levels? JEDEC standards. SDRAM packages and protocols? JEDEC. ESD compliance? JEDEC.

Both of them however are plagued by bureocracy (IPC7352 for example is *years* behind with the current practice) so, in fact, most manufactures have their own custom packages, for example. So, for example, you probably won't find some modern 5x6mm MOSFET package, neither as package for JEDEC nor as soldering guide on IPC. In my experience *all* the major manufacturers deviates from them at least on the more 'innovative' parts.